# Debian wheezy - hanging on shutdown

Tags: debian, kvm, shutdown

My debian system hangs when I'm trying to shutdown/reboot. It hangs on:

> kvm: exiting hardware virtualization

(infinitely blinking white cursor)
I've tried to shutdown by gui and by `poweroff`/`shutdown -h` now.
I've tried to insert in grub config file "`acpi=off`" and "`acpi=force`" (I've read that it could help me) but no effect.

How can I diagnose and resolve this problem?

Comment: Is the Debian running in a virtual machine?

Comment: No, Debian is running as standalone system.

Comment: I have this issue on Arch Linux, after some late night half-way-done tinkering with hardware virtualization. I bet i missed to clean a config file somewhere from my nightly adventures. Or possibly some kernel module that is loaded unnecessary...

Comment: I have the same problem but I am using a Chromebook. Have you tried [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263179/get-rid-of-kvm-disabled-by-bios/312858)?  `lsmod | grep kvm` Then create a file to backlist the kvm.